# How to relocation tree node to avoid Collision in GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jgraphx

I have defined a class called LogicalNode,which can be used to form a tree.I want to display the whole tree,but i don't know how to set the location for each node.In the program, I can insert a tree node under his father node, so when i insert some nodes, it can lead to collision between nodes.
Here's my Class:

```
public class LogicalNode implements Serializable{
private String text;
private String logicalType;
private LogicalNode parent;
private LinkedList<LogicalNode> sons = new LinkedList<>();
private List<LogicalNode> tmpNodes = new ArrayList<>();

public LogicalNode(){}

public LogicalNode(String text,String logicalType,LogicalNode parent){
    this.text = text;
    this.logicalType = logicalType;
    this.parent = parent;
}

public void addSon(LogicalNode node){
    this.sons.offer(node);
    this.tmpNodes.add(node);
}

public int getOrder(){
    LogicalNode parent = this.getParent();
    if(parent == null){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return parent.getSons().indexOf(this);
    }
}

public int getLevel(){
    LogicalNode node = this;
    int level = 0;
    while(node.getParent() != null){
        node = node.getParent();
        level++;
    }
    return level;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.text;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getLogicalType() {
    return logicalType;
}

public void setLogicalType(String logicalType) {
    this.logicalType = logicalType;
}

public LogicalNode getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public void setParent(LogicalNode parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

public LinkedList<LogicalNode> getSons() {
    return sons;
}

public void setSons(LinkedList<LogicalNode> sons) {
    this.sons = sons;
}

public List<LogicalNode> getTmpNodes() {
    return tmpNodes;
}

public void setTmpNodes(List<LogicalNode> tmpNodes) {
    this.tmpNodes = tmpNodes;
}

}
```

This class can used as user Object to some GUI components to display it,such as mxCell in JGraphX.

Comment: You kind of need to think about like layers or rows.  Each row will have a defined number of child numbers (from parents), which then, together define the overall size of the row, this in turn also has an effect on the parent node positions (as a parent with many children will need to be positioned different then a parent with a few children).

Comment: I'd start out simply, start by determining the overall width of each row and left align all the nodes, if possible, relative to the next row of children. You could even start out by giving equal weight to each "column". Once you can walk the whole tree and calculate the size of each "row", you'll be in a better position to make other determinations

Comment: Thanks,I'm using JGraphx library to display,and I'm going to try to find something like TreeModel.